# Custom Android SeekBar has invisible progress bar, why?

Tags: seekbar, android-progressbar

Hi I am writing a custom seek bar to display the progress on the thumb. The method I am using is to override the setOnProgressChangeListener method and replace it with a new listener with code that replaces the thumb with a thumb that has the text on it. It works fine, except that the progress bar has disappeared! Here is my custom class:

```
public class ProgressDisplayingSeekBar extends SeekBar {
  private static final String TAG = ProgressDisplayingSeekBar.class.getSimpleName();

  private Paint mTextPaint;
  private Bitmap mOriginalThumbBitmap;

  private static OnSeekBarChangeListener DummyOnSeekBarProgressChangedListener =
      new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
          // Dummy
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // Dummy
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // Dummy
        }
      };

  public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
  }

  public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mTextPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_dark_bg));
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.progress_button_text_size));
    mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed", Typeface.NORMAL));

    initThumb();
    setOnSeekBarChangeListener(DummyOnSeekBarProgressChangedListener);
  }

  private void initThumb() {
    Drawable thumbDrawable = this.getThumb();
    mOriginalThumbBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
        thumbDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mOriginalThumbBitmap);
    thumbDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    thumbDrawable.draw(canvas);
    updateThumbWithProgressDisplay();
  }

  @Override
  public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(final OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener) {
    OnSeekBarChangeListener progressDisplayingOnSeekBarChangeListener =
        new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            onSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(seekBar, progress, fromUser);
            updateThumbWithProgressDisplay();
          }

          @Override
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            onSeekBarChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar);
          }

          @Override
          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            onSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar);
          }
        };

    super.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(progressDisplayingOnSeekBarChangeListener);
  }

  private void updateThumbWithProgressDisplay() {
    Bitmap newThumbBitmap = mOriginalThumbBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newThumbBitmap);
    String progressDisplaytext = Integer.toString(this.getProgress());
    int width = (int) mTextPaint.measureText(progressDisplaytext);
    int y = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent()) / 2));
    canvas.drawText(progressDisplaytext,
        (newThumbBitmap.getWidth() - width) / 2,
        y,
        mTextPaint);
    this.setThumb(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), newThumbBitmap));
  }
}
```

How can I get the original progress bar (gray line with blue fill) back?

**EDIT:**

I ended up having to use my own progress drawable that looks like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
      <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#00b0b0b0"
            android:centerColor="#b0b0b0"
            android:endColor="#00b0b0b0"/>
      </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
      <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/light_blue"/>
      </shape>
    </clip>
  </item>

  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
      <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/light_blue"/>
      </shape>
    </clip>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

and setting fixing the XML of the Progress Drawable with this:

```
      android:minHeight="4dp"
      android:maxHeight="4dp"
      android:thumb="@drawable/my_thumb"
      android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_progress"/>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm running into the same problem with a custom subclass of SeekBar.

Comment: I never found a good solution, but I updated my question with how I worked around it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. I found that if I place my custom SeekBar into a view programmatically, it appears as expected with the system graphics. But if I place it into a view via XML, it's functional but invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is with the constructors in your custom SeekBar class. I had set mine up the same way after seeing this approach in multiple StackOverflow answers:

```
public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // setup code goes here
}
```

But I had a feeling the second constructor, which would be needed to pass the XML attributes to the SeekBar, wasn't running correctly. I changed it to this:

```
public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context, null, 0);
}

public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // setup code goes here
}
```

But still no luck. Then I tried this:

```
public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init();
}

public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init();
}

public ProgressDisplayingSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.init();
}

public void init() {
    // setup code goes here
}
```

Success! Creating a separate method for the setup code is a bit less elegant than using one of the existing constructor methods, but it's a simple fix if you want to use the default slider graphics.

I don't know if the answers advocating one of the other approaches are just wrong, or if this has changed since earlier Android versions, or something else.